# HTML/CSS table messes up layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a very simple website in HTML/CSS. It's all working fine until I add a table. Then my footer gets placed above my content and the background of my body dissapears. Does anyone know how to fix this?
This is how it's supposed to look, but with the table instead of text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D0GZ.jpg
This is how it looks now:https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdHK9.jpg
Thank you!

Comment: can you post your code please ?

Comment: I've uploaded them here: http://codeshare.io/gKW1u    thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have webpage live anywhere?  It would help a ton to see the code.

I typically have problems with Tables placing code in funny places on the the page if I miss closing a table tag.  Maybe a tr/td closing tag was forgotten.

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>row1cell1</td>
          <td>row1cell2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>row2cell1</td>
          <td>row2cell2</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I've checked and I closed them all. I uploaded my code here: http://codeshare.io/gKW1u thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to close the table with `</table>`

Comment: Don't worry, everybody have made mistakes like this :)